# Is there any way to programatically create hyper-v machines?

Tags: visual-c++, hyper-v

Is there any way to programatically( in C++ ) create hyper-v machines. I've hypervisor installed in Windows 2k8 R2 server.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. If you can do something with a mouse you can do it by code too. However what have you tried?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the existing vm information, can do start and shutdown the VM's using hyper-v WMI api's.
But havn't foung API's for creating new VM.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to start from an PowerScript example and work back to what the C++ should be.

Here is [an example that uses WMI to create VM object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/05/28/scripting-vm-creation-with-hyper-v.aspx).  The WMI objects will be the same in C++, so you should be able to translate this example.

Next, you need to attach a VHD to the VM to act as root device, and you'll want to start that VM.  For a detailed example have a look at [how OpenStack's Hyper-V driver implements VM creation](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/nova/virt/hyperv/vmops.py).  Again, the WMI objects are the same in C++, so you should be able to translate to C++